# How does a tow recursive function in the same line are manipulated by the compiler?

Tags: c++

I need to understand how the compiler calculate the result of two recursive function in the same line does it calculate the first then go to the second or does it make both of them in parallel the code below suppose to calculate the height of a node in a binary search tree but i can't fully understand how it works

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class BSTNode {
private:
   T key;
   BSTNode* left;
   BSTNode* right;
public:
   BSTNode(){
   left = right = 0;
   }
   BSTNode(T& k, BSTNode* l = 0, BSTNode* r = 0){
       key   = k;
       left  = l;
       right = r;
    }
BSTNode* getLeft(){
    return left;
}
BSTNode* getRight(){
    return right;
}
T getKey(){
    return key;
}
 };

 template <class T>
    class BSTFCI {
 protected:
    BSTNode<T>* root;
  public:
BSTFCI (){
    root = 0;
}
int height(BSTNode<T>* node){
    if(node == 0)
        return 0;
    else{
        if(height(node->left) > height(node->right))///does it calculate the height of the left and the right together or what
            return (1+height(node->left));
        else
            return (1+height(node->right));
    }
}
};
```

Comment: There is nothing happening in parallel here, one function is called after the other

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly the same as non-recursive finctions. (This is the most important thing to understand about recursive functions.)

Comment: can you explain how it works

Comment: @molbdnilo 'To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion’ — Recursion Explained

Comment: @UnholySheep when the height of right node is called? as it will go until the left is null

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this link would clarify: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

> Order of evaluation
>
> Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators (including the
>   order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call
>   expression and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within
>   any expression) **is unspecified**. The compiler can evaluate operands in
>   any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is
>   evaluated again

Thus, if you want to make it compiler independent, first, call those recursions in the order your programming logic requires, and then pass returned values to comparison operator.

```
//does it calculate the height of the left and the right together or what
```

so, it's either calculated left to right, or right to left (but not concurrently/simultaneously - for that it would be required to run them in separate threads)